# Test a SQL script before committing to it PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

In PSQL, preferably from within pgAdmin, how can I see what the result of like an UPDATE or INSERT script will be without, you know, actually running it and modifying anything?

Comment: Do you mean, how can you run it without the result committing?

Comment: `BEGIN; YOUR DML; WHATEVER; ROLLBACK;`

Comment: @zerkms has your answer. Do some reading on transactions - such as this one: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31206&seqNum=6

Comment: begin transaction; commit transaction;